# Writing to file using CSV adds extraneous quotes

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading string values from a .tsv file, filtering, and writing to a new one. When a row's item has double-quotes, it doubles them and adds surrounding quotes to the item. For example:

```
with open ("test.tsv", "wb") as fp:
    fp = csv.writer (fp, delimiter='\t')
    fp.writerow (["test"])
    fp.writerow (["Oh no! \"They\" are here!"])
```

This creates the following items in test.tsv:

> test
>
> "Oh no! ""They"" are here!"

I looked everywhere and couldn't find out why it does this or what I can do to change it. I want it to maintain quotes and not duplicate, so the preferred test.tsv would be:

> test
>
> Oh no! "They" are here!

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: That's expected behaviour for something that reads CSV to know they're actual quotes... look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE

Comment: The .tsv I read in doesn't have them and it reads it fine, so I'm not sure what you mean. And do you know of a way to solve my issue?

Comment: I tried csv.writer (fp, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\') and ended up with: Oh no! \"They\" are here! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` and `quotechar=None`.  Then quotes will not be escaped.

Then you should set the `escapechar` so that your delimiter is escaped should it appear in a field.  (Thanks to @dano for mentioning this)

```
import csv
with open ("test.tsv", "wb") as fp:
    fp = csv.writer (fp, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None, escapechar="|")
    fp.writerow (["test"])
    fp.writerow (['Oh no! "They" are here!'])
```

Keep in mind that your current examples don't give any reason to be in csv/tsv, since there are no separate fields.

Comment: Bravo, seems to work on both single and double quotes, thanks!

Comment: @Befall Note that `csv` will raise an exception if any instances of `delimiter` show up in the text you try to write when you do this. You need to set `escapechar` if that's a concern.